# How can I mock a function called from a dictionary?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

test.py:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_b_called(mocker):
    b = mocker.patch('app.service.b')

    service.a('b')
    assert b.called
```

service.py:

```
def a(type):
    _actions[type]()

def b():
    pass

_actions = { 'b': b }
```

My test will fail as my patch does not work as I expected.  What am I doing wrong here?  This definitely works if `a` calls `b` directly and not using that dictionary.  I have tested for this.  I know you can mock a dictionary with `patch.dict` but then how would I test that `b` was called?

Comment: What if I'm not sure whether it's going to be on a dict at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to mock the dictionary action with a function that does nothing.  Instead, I should have mocked it to a `MagicMock` function which is what a patch does as well.

```
patch.dict(
    'app.service._actions',
    {'b': MagicMock} # MagicMock is imported from unittest.mock
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I would argue that these are two separate unit tests, one for function a and one for the dictionary _actions.

_actions is not just a simple dictionary but in a sense a dynamic function call. So if you are truly testing just function a then you need to patch the _actions object and just test the functionality in the scope of the function.

_actions is out of the testing scope and should be tested individually like any other method.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from stack_overflow import a,b,c, _actions

class TestStack(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super().tearDown()

    @patch.dict('stack_overflow._actions',{'b':b})
    def test_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(5,a('b'))

    def test__actions_def_b(self):
        self.assertEqual(_actions['b'],b)

    def test__actions_def_c(self):
        self.assertEqual(_actions['c'],c)
```

```
def a(type):
    current_actions = _actions
    return _actions[type]()

def b():
    return 5

def c():
    return 7

_actions = { 'b': b, 'c': c}
```

Comment: I do have separate test(s) for `b`, I just want to show that `b` is called in my test for `a`.

Comment: Not a separate test for b, but a separate test for _actions, the object you are depending on for routing to specific functions you are trying to call